# Help me understand the offset values for pdfpages, for a non-standard page setup (a4 landscape, divided in three along the vertical axis)

Tags: pdfpages, printing

This is my pdfpages tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1,3,5},nup=3x1,noautoscale=true,landscape,offset=-124 -124]{a4pecha}
\includepdf[pages={6,4,2},nup=3x1,noautoscale=true,landscape,offset=-124 -124]{a4pecha}
\end{document}
```

This is the tex file used to generate a4pecha.pdf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{tikz}

\geometry{paperwidth=29.7cm,paperheight=7cm,margin=0cm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newdynamicframe{29.7cm}{7cm}{0cm}{0cm}[standard]
\setdynamiccontents*{standard}{
\vfil\hfil
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=black,very thick] (2.7,.93) rectangle +(24.3,5.14)
  (2.77,1) rectangle +(24.16,5)
  (3.77,1) rectangle +(.07,5)
  (25.97,1) rectangle +(.07,5);
\node[rotate=-90] at (3.3,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
\node[rotate=90] at (26.47,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newflowframe{21.7cm}{4.9cm}{4cm}{.9cm}

\setdefaultlanguage{tibetan}
\setmainfont{Tibetan Machine Uni}
\newfontfamily{\maintext}{Tibetan Machine Uni}
\begin{document}
\Large ༄༅། །ཕྱི་ལོ་ ༢༠༡༤ ཟླ་ ༦ ཚེས་ ༡༣ ཉིན་གྱི་སྔ་དྲོའི་ཆུ་ཚོད་ ༩།༣༠ ནས་ ༡༢།༣༠ ཙམ་བར་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་དྲུང་ཆེ་བཀྲ་ཤིས་ཕུན་ཚོགས་ལགས་ཀྱིས་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་ལྷག་པ་ཚེ་རིང་དྲན་རྟེན་ཚོགས་ཁང་ནང་རྒྱ་གར་གྱི་རྒྱལ་ས་ལྡི་ལིར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་༸གོང་ས་༸སྐྱབས་མགོན་ཏཱ་ལའི་བླ་མ་མཆོག་གི་ཀུན་ཕན་བདེ་རྩས་གོ་སྒྲིག་འོག་རྒྱ་གར་རྒྱལ་ཡོངས་མཐོ་སློབ་ཁག་ ༢༩ ནང་སློབ་གཉེར་བྱེད་བཞིན་པའི་སློབ་ཕྲུག་གྲངས་ ༣༣ དང་ཐུག་འཕྲད་ཀྱིས་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་སྒྲོམ་གཞི་དང་སྲིད་བྱུས། དེ་བཞིན་ལྷན་ཁང་ཁག་གི་བྱེད་སྒོ་རྣམ་གསུམ་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་འབྲེལ་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ངོས་ནས་དབུ་མའི་ལམ་གྱི་སྲིད་བྱུས་གཞིར་བཟུང་རྒྱ་ནག་གཞུང་དང་ལྷན་དུ་འབྲེལ་མོལ་བརྒྱུད་བོད་དོན་བདེན་མཐའ་གསལ་ཐབས་ལ་འབད་བརྩོན་ཞུ་བཞིན་ཡོད་སྐོར་སོགས་ཀྱི་གསུང་བཤད་ཟབ་རྒྱས་གནང་བ་མ་ཟད། དྲི་བར་ལན་འདེབས་ཀྱང་གནང་།སློབ་ཕྲུག་དེ་དག་ལ་ཟླ་བ་གཅིག་རིང་བཞུགས་སྒར་རྡ་སའི་ཁུལ་གྱི་བོད་པའི་དགོན་སྡེ་ཁག་ནང་བོད་ཀྱི་ཐུན་མིན་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་སོགས་ཀྱི་སྐོར་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་སྦྱོང་བརྡར་སྤྲོད་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག སྤྱིར་སྒུ་རུ་ཀུལ་ (Gurukul Programme) ལས་འཆར་འདི་བཞིན་ཐོག་མར་ཕྱི་ལོ་ ༡༩༩༤ ལོར་འགོ་བཙུགས་གནང་བ་དང། དེ་སྔ་ལས་འཆར་འདིའི་འོག་མཐོ་སློབ་ཀྱི་སློབ་མ་དྲུག་བདུན་ཙམ་ལས་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མེད་ཀྱང་། འདས་པའི་ལོ་དྲུག་གི་སྔོན་ཙམ་ནས་ལས་འཆར་དེར་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མང་དུ་ཕྱིན་ནས་ལོ་ལྟར་སློབ་མ་བུ་བཅོ་ལྔ་དང་བུ་མོ་བཅོ་ལྔ་བདམས་ནས་རྡ་སར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་བོད་པའི་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་། གོམས་གཤིས་སོགས་ཉམས་མྱོང་གསོག་རྒྱུ་ཙམ་མ་ཟད། བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ལས་ཁུངས་མ་ལག་དང་བཅས་པ་ཤེས་རྟོགས་བྱ་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག་ལོ་ ༢༠༡༤ ཟླ་ ༦ ཚེས་ ༡༣ ཉིན་གྱི་སྔ་དྲོའི་ཆུ་ཚོད་ ༩།༣༠ ནས་ ༡༢།༣༠ ཙམ་བར་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་དྲུང་ཆེ་བཀྲ་ཤིས་ཕུན་ཚོགས་ལགས་ཀྱིས་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་ལྷག་པ་ཚེ་རིང་དྲན་རྟེན་ཚོགས་ཁང་ནང་རྒྱ་གར་གྱི་རྒྱལ་ས་ལྡི་ལིར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་༸གོང་ས་༸སྐྱབས་མགོན་ཏཱ་ལའི་བླ་མ་མཆོག་གི་ཀུན་ཕན་བདེ་རྩས་གོ་སྒྲིག་འོག་རྒྱ་གར་རྒྱལ་ཡོངས་མཐོ་སློབ་ཁག་ ༢༩ ནང་སློབ་གཉེར་བྱེད་བཞིན་པའི་སློབ་ཕྲུག་གྲངས་ ༣༣ དང་ཐུག་འཕྲད་ཀྱིས་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་སྒྲོམ་གཞི་དང་སྲིད་བྱུས། དེ་བཞིན་ལྷན་ཁང་ཁག་གི་བྱེད་སྒོ་རྣམ་གསུམ་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་འབྲེལ་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ངོས་ནས་དབུ་མའི་ལམ་གྱི་སྲིད་བྱུས་གཞིར་བཟུང་རྒྱ་ནག་གཞུང་དང་ལྷན་དུ་འབྲེལ་མོལ་བརྒྱུད་བོད་དོན་བདེན་མཐའ་གསལ་ཐབས་ལ་འབད་བརྩོན་ཞུ་བཞིན་ཡོད་སྐོར་སོགས་ཀྱི་གསུང་བཤད་ཟབ་རྒྱས་གནང་བ་མ་ཟད། དྲི་བར་ལན་འདེབས་ཀྱང་གནང་།སློབ་ཕྲུག་དེ་དག་ལ་ཟླ་བ་གཅིག་རིང་བཞུགས་སྒར་རྡ་སའི་ཁུལ་གྱི་བོད་པའི་དགོན་སྡེ་ཁག་ནང་བོད་ཀྱི་ཐུན་མིན་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་སོགས་ཀྱི་སྐོར་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་སྦྱོང་བརྡར་སྤྲོད་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག སྤྱིར་སྒུ་རུ་ཀུལ་ (Gurukul Programme) ལས་འཆར་འདི་བཞིན་ཐོག་མར་ཕྱི་ལོ་ ༡༩༩༤ ལོར་འགོ་བཙུགས་གནང་བ་དང། དེ་སྔ་ལས་འཆར་འདིའི་འོག་མཐོ་སློབ་ཀྱི་སློབ་མ་དྲུག་བདུན་ཙམ་ལས་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མེད་ཀྱང་། འདས་པའི་ལོ་དྲུག་གི་སྔོན་ཙམ་ནས་ལས་འཆར་དེར་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མང་དུ་ཕྱིན་ནས་ལོ་ལྟར་སློབ་མ་བུ་བཅོ་ལྔ་དང་བུ་མོ་བཅོ་ལྔ་བདམས་ནས་རྡ་སར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་བོད་པའི་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་། གོམས་གཤིས་སོགས་ཉམས་མྱོང་གསོག་རྒྱུ་ཙམ་མ་ཟད། བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ལས་ཁུངས་མ་ལག་དང་བཅས་པ་ཤེས་རྟོགས་བྱ་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག་ལོ་ ༢༠༡༤ ཟླ་ ༦ ཚེས་ ༡༣ ཉིན་གྱི་སྔ་དྲོའི་ཆུ་ཚོད་ ༩།༣༠ ནས་ ༡༢།༣༠ ཙམ་བར་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་དྲུང་ཆེ་བཀྲ་ཤིས་ཕུན་ཚོགས་ལགས་ཀྱིས་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་ལྷག་པ་ཚེ་རིང་དྲན་རྟེན་ཚོགས་ཁང་ནང་རྒྱ་གར་གྱི་རྒྱལ་ས་ལྡི་ལིར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་༸གོང་ས་༸སྐྱབས་མགོན་ཏཱ་ལའི་བླ་མ་མཆོག་གི་ཀུན་ཕན་བདེ་རྩས་གོ་སྒྲིག་འོག་རྒྱ་གར་རྒྱལ་ཡོངས་མཐོ་སློབ་ཁག་ ༢༩ ནང་སློབ་གཉེར་བྱེད་བཞིན་པའི་སློབ་ཕྲུག་གྲངས་ ༣༣ དང་ཐུག་འཕྲད་ཀྱིས་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་སྒྲོམ་གཞི་དང་སྲིད་བྱུས། དེ་བཞིན་ལྷན་ཁང་ཁག་གི་བྱེད་སྒོ་རྣམ་གསུམ་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་འབྲེལ་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ངོས་ནས་དབུ་མའི་ལམ་གྱི་སྲིད་བྱུས་གཞིར་བཟུང་རྒྱ་ནག་གཞུང་དང་ལྷན་དུ་འབྲེལ་མོལ་བརྒྱུད་བོད་དོན་བདེན་མཐའ་གསལ་ཐབས་ལ་འབད་བརྩོན་ཞུ་བཞིན་ཡོད་སྐོར་སོགས་ཀྱི་གསུང་བཤད་ཟབ་རྒྱས་གནང་བ་མ་ཟད། དྲི་བར་ལན་འདེབས་ཀྱང་གནང་།སློབ་ཕྲུག་དེ་དག་ལ་ཟླ་བ་གཅིག་རིང་བཞུགས་སྒར་རྡ་སའི་ཁུལ་གྱི་བོད་པའི་དགོན་སྡེ་ཁག་ནང་བོད་ཀྱི་ཐུན་མིན་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་སོགས་ཀྱི་སྐོར་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་སྦྱོང་བརྡར་སྤྲོད་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག སྤྱིར་སྒུ་རུ་ཀུལ་ (Gurukul Programme) ལས་འཆར་འདི་བཞིན་ཐོག་མར་ཕྱི་ལོ་ ༡༩༩༤ ལོར་འགོ་བཙུགས་གནང་བ་དང། དེ་སྔ་ལས་འཆར་འདིའི་འོག་མཐོ་སློབ་ཀྱི་སློབ་མ་དྲུག་བདུན་ཙམ་ལས་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མེད་ཀྱང་། འདས་པའི་ལོ་དྲུག་གི་སྔོན་ཙམ་ནས་ལས་འཆར་དེར་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མང་དུ་ཕྱིན་ནས་ལོ་ལྟར་སློབ་མ་བུ་བཅོ་ལྔ་དང་བུ་མོ་བཅོ་ལྔ་བདམས་ནས་རྡ་སར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་བོད་པའི་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་། གོམས་གཤིས་སོགས་ཉམས་མྱོང་གསོག་རྒྱུ་ཙམ་མ་ཟད། བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ལས་ཁུངས་མ་ལག་དང་བཅས་པ་ཤེས་རྟོགས་བྱ་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག་ལོ་ ༢༠༡༤ ཟླ་ ༦ ཚེས་ ༡༣ ཉིན་གྱི་སྔ་དྲོའི་ཆུ་ཚོད་ ༩།༣༠ ནས་ ༡༢།༣༠ ཙམ་བར་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་དྲུང་ཆེ་བཀྲ་ཤིས་ཕུན་ཚོགས་ལགས་ཀྱིས་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་ལྷག་པ་ཚེ་རིང་དྲན་རྟེན་ཚོགས་ཁང་ནང་རྒྱ་གར་གྱི་རྒྱལ་ས་ལྡི་ལིར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་༸གོང་ས་༸སྐྱབས་མགོན་ཏཱ་ལའི་བླ་མ་མཆོག་གི་ཀུན་ཕན་བདེ་རྩས་གོ་སྒྲིག་འོག་རྒྱ་གར་རྒྱལ་ཡོངས་མཐོ་སློབ་ཁག་ ༢༩ ནང་སློབ་གཉེར་བྱེད་བཞིན་པའི་སློབ་ཕྲུག་གྲངས་ ༣༣ དང་ཐུག་འཕྲད་ཀྱིས་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་སྒྲོམ་གཞི་དང་སྲིད་བྱུས། དེ་བཞིན་ལྷན་ཁང་ཁག་གི་བྱེད་སྒོ་རྣམ་གསུམ་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་འབྲེལ་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ངོས་ནས་དབུ་མའི་ལམ་གྱི་སྲིད་བྱུས་གཞིར་བཟུང་རྒྱ་ནག་གཞུང་དང་ལྷན་དུ་འབྲེལ་མོལ་བརྒྱུད་བོད་དོན་བདེན་མཐའ་གསལ་ཐབས་ལ་འབད་བརྩོན་ཞུ་བཞིན་ཡོད་སྐོར་སོགས་ཀྱི་གསུང་བཤད་ཟབ་རྒྱས་གནང་བ་མ་ཟད། དྲི་བར་ལན་འདེབས་ཀྱང་གནང་།སློབ་ཕྲུག་དེ་དག་ལ་ཟླ་བ་གཅིག་རིང་བཞུགས་སྒར་རྡ་སའི་ཁུལ་གྱི་བོད་པའི་དགོན་སྡེ་ཁག་ནང་བོད་ཀྱི་ཐུན་མིན་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་སོགས་ཀྱི་སྐོར་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་སྦྱོང་བརྡར་སྤྲོད་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག སྤྱིར་སྒུ་རུ་ཀུལ་ (Gurukul Programme) ལས་འཆར་འདི་བཞིན་ཐོག་མར་ཕྱི་ལོ་ ༡༩༩༤ ལོར་འགོ་བཙུགས་གནང་བ་དང། དེ་སྔ་ལས་འཆར་འདིའི་འོག་མཐོ་སློབ་ཀྱི་སློབ་མ་དྲུག་བདུན་ཙམ་ལས་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མེད་ཀྱང་། འདས་པའི་ལོ་དྲུག་གི་སྔོན་ཙམ་ནས་ལས་འཆར་དེར་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མང་དུ་ཕྱིན་ནས་ལོ་ལྟར་སློབ་མ་བུ་བཅོ་ལྔ་དང་བུ་མོ་བཅོ་ལྔ་བདམས་ནས་རྡ་སར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་བོད་པའི་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་། གོམས་གཤིས་སོགས་ཉམས་མྱོང་གསོག་རྒྱུ་ཙམ་མ་ཟད། བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ལས་ཁུངས་མ་ལག་དང་བཅས་པ་ཤེས་རྟོགས་བྱ་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག་ལོ་ ༢༠༡༤ ཟླ་ ༦ ཚེས་ ༡༣ ཉིན་གྱི་སྔ་དྲོའི་ཆུ་ཚོད་ ༩།༣༠ ནས་ ༡༢།༣༠ ཙམ་བར་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་དྲུང་ཆེ་བཀྲ་ཤིས་ཕུན་ཚོགས་ལགས་ཀྱིས་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་ལྷག་པ་ཚེ་རིང་དྲན་རྟེན་ཚོགས་ཁང་ནང་རྒྱ་གར་གྱི་རྒྱལ་ས་ལྡི་ལིར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་༸གོང་ས་༸སྐྱབས་མགོན་ཏཱ་ལའི་བླ་མ་མཆོག་གི་ཀུན་ཕན་བདེ་རྩས་གོ་སྒྲིག་འོག་རྒྱ་གར་རྒྱལ་ཡོངས་མཐོ་སློབ་ཁག་ ༢༩ ནང་སློབ་གཉེར་བྱེད་བཞིན་པའི་སློབ་ཕྲུག་གྲངས་ ༣༣ དང་ཐུག་འཕྲད་ཀྱིས་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་སྒྲོམ་གཞི་དང་སྲིད་བྱུས། དེ་བཞིན་ལྷན་ཁང་ཁག་གི་བྱེད་སྒོ་རྣམ་གསུམ་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་འབྲེལ་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ངོས་ནས་དབུ་མའི་ལམ་གྱི་སྲིད་བྱུས་གཞིར་བཟུང་རྒྱ་ནག་གཞུང་དང་ལྷན་དུ་འབྲེལ་མོལ་བརྒྱུད་བོད་དོན་བདེན་མཐའ་གསལ་ཐབས་ལ་འབད་བརྩོན་ཞུ་བཞིན་ཡོད་སྐོར་སོགས་ཀྱི་གསུང་བཤད་ཟབ་རྒྱས་གནང་བ་མ་ཟད། དྲི་བར་ལན་འདེབས་ཀྱང་གནང་།སློབ་ཕྲུག་དེ་དག་ལ་ཟླ་བ་གཅིག་རིང་བཞུགས་སྒར་རྡ་སའི་ཁུལ་གྱི་བོད་པའི་དགོན་སྡེ་ཁག་ནང་བོད་ཀྱི་ཐུན་མིན་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་སོགས་ཀྱི་སྐོར་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་སྦྱོང་བརྡར་སྤྲོད་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག སྤྱིར་སྒུ་རུ་ཀུལ་ (Gurukul Programme) ལས་འཆར་འདི་བཞིན་ཐོག་མར་ཕྱི་ལོ་ ༡༩༩༤ ལོར་འགོ་བཙུགས་གནང་བ་དང། དེ་སྔ་ལས་འཆར་འདིའི་འོག་མཐོ་སློབ་ཀྱི་སློབ་མ་དྲུག་བདུན་ཙམ་ལས་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མེད་ཀྱང་། འདས་པའི་ལོ་དྲུག་གི་སྔོན་ཙམ་ནས་ལས་འཆར་དེར་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མང་དུ་ཕྱིན་ནས་ལོ་ལྟར་སློབ་མ་བུ་བཅོ་ལྔ་དང་བུ་མོ་བཅོ་ལྔ་བདམས་ནས་རྡ་སར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་བོད་པའི་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་། གོམས་གཤིས་སོགས་ཉམས་མྱོང་གསོག་རྒྱུ་ཙམ་མ་ཟད། བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ལས་ཁུངས་མ་ལག་དང་བཅས་པ་ཤེས་རྟོགས་བྱ་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག་ལོ་ ༢༠༡༤ ཟླ་ ༦ ཚེས་ ༡༣ ཉིན་གྱི་སྔ་དྲོའི་ཆུ་ཚོད་ ༩།༣༠ ནས་ ༡༢།༣༠ ཙམ་བར་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་དྲུང་ཆེ་བཀྲ་ཤིས་ཕུན་ཚོགས་ལགས་ཀྱིས་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་ལྷག་པ་ཚེ་རིང་དྲན་རྟེན་ཚོགས་ཁང་ནང་རྒྱ་གར་གྱི་རྒྱལ་ས་ལྡི་ལིར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་༸གོང་ས་༸སྐྱབས་མགོན་ཏཱ་ལའི་བླ་མ་མཆོག་གི་ཀུན་ཕན་བདེ་རྩས་གོ་སྒྲིག་འོག་རྒྱ་གར་རྒྱལ་ཡོངས་མཐོ་སློབ་ཁག་ ༢༩ ནང་སློབ་གཉེར་བྱེད་བཞིན་པའི་སློབ་ཕྲུག་གྲངས་ ༣༣ དང་ཐུག་འཕྲད་ཀྱིས་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་སྒྲོམ་གཞི་དང་སྲིད་བྱུས། དེ་བཞིན་ལྷན་ཁང་ཁག་གི་བྱེད་སྒོ་རྣམ་གསུམ་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་འབྲེལ་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ངོས་ནས་དབུ་མའི་ལམ་གྱི་སྲིད་བྱུས་གཞིར་བཟུང་རྒྱ་ནག་གཞུང་དང་ལྷན་དུ་འབྲེལ་མོལ་བརྒྱུད་བོད་དོན་བདེན་མཐའ་གསལ་ཐབས་ལ་འབད་བརྩོན་ཞུ་བཞིན་ཡོད་སྐོར་སོགས་ཀྱི་གསུང་བཤད་ཟབ་རྒྱས་གནང་བ་མ་ཟད། དྲི་བར་ལན་འདེབས་ཀྱང་གནང་།སློབ་ཕྲུག་དེ་དག་ལ་ཟླ་བ་གཅིག་རིང་བཞུགས་སྒར་རྡ་སའི་ཁུལ་གྱི་བོད་པའི་དགོན་སྡེ་ཁག་ནང་བོད་ཀྱི་ཐུན་མིན་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་སོགས་ཀྱི་སྐོར་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་སྦྱོང་བརྡར་སྤྲོད་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག སྤྱིར་སྒུ་རུ་ཀུལ་ (Gurukul Programme) ལས་འཆར་འདི་བཞིན་ཐོག་མར་ཕྱི་ལོ་ ༡༩༩༤ ལོར་འགོ་བཙུགས་གནང་བ་དང། དེ་སྔ་ལས་འཆར་འདིའི་འོག་མཐོ་སློབ་ཀྱི་སློབ་མ་དྲུག་བདུན་ཙམ་ལས་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མེད་ཀྱང་། འདས་པའི་ལོ་དྲུག་གི་སྔོན་ཙམ་ནས་ལས་འཆར་དེར་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མང་དུ་ཕྱིན་ནས་ལོ་ལྟར་སློབ་མ་བུ་བཅོ་ལྔ་དང་བུ་མོ་བཅོ་ལྔ་བདམས་ནས་རྡ་སར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་བོད་པའི་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་། གོམས་གཤིས་སོགས་ཉམས་མྱོང་གསོག་རྒྱུ་ཙམ་མ་ཟད། བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ལས་ཁུངས་མ་ལག་དང་བཅས་པ་ཤེས་རྟོགས་བྱ་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག་ལོ་ ༢༠༡༤ ཟླ་ ༦ ཚེས་ ༡༣ ཉིན་གྱི་སྔ་དྲོའི་ཆུ་ཚོད་ ༩།༣༠ ནས་ ༡༢།༣༠ ཙམ་བར་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་དྲུང་ཆེ་བཀྲ་ཤིས་ཕུན་ཚོགས་ལགས་ཀྱིས་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་ལྷག་པ་ཚེ་རིང་དྲན་རྟེན་ཚོགས་ཁང་ནང་རྒྱ་གར་གྱི་རྒྱལ་ས་ལྡི་ལིར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་༸གོང་ས་༸སྐྱབས་མགོན་ཏཱ་ལའི་བླ་མ་མཆོག་གི་ཀུན་ཕན་བདེ་རྩས་གོ་སྒྲིག་འོག་རྒྱ་གར་རྒྱལ་ཡོངས་མཐོ་སློབ་ཁག་ ༢༩ ནང་སློབ་གཉེར་བྱེད་བཞིན་པའི་སློབ་ཕྲུག་གྲངས་ ༣༣ དང་ཐུག་འཕྲད་ཀྱིས་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་སྒྲོམ་གཞི་དང་སྲིད་བྱུས། དེ་བཞིན་ལྷན་ཁང་ཁག་གི་བྱེད་སྒོ་རྣམ་གསུམ་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་འབྲེལ་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ངོས་ནས་དབུ་མའི་ལམ་གྱི་སྲིད་བྱུས་གཞིར་བཟུང་རྒྱ་ནག་གཞུང་དང་ལྷན་དུ་འབྲེལ་མོལ་བརྒྱུད་བོད་དོན་བདེན་མཐའ་གསལ་ཐབས་ལ་འབད་བརྩོན་ཞུ་བཞིན་ཡོད་སྐོར་སོགས་ཀྱི་གསུང་བཤད་ཟབ་རྒྱས་གནང་བ་མ་ཟད། དྲི་བར་ལན་འདེབས་ཀྱང་གནང་།སློབ་ཕྲུག་དེ་དག་ལ་ཟླ་བ་གཅིག་རིང་བཞུགས་སྒར་རྡ་སའི་ཁུལ་གྱི་བོད་པའི་དགོན་སྡེ་ཁག་ནང་བོད་ཀྱི་ཐུན་མིན་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་སོགས་ཀྱི་སྐོར་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་སྦྱོང་བརྡར་སྤྲོད་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག སྤྱིར་སྒུ་རུ་ཀུལ་ (Gurukul Programme) ལས་འཆར་འདི་བཞིན་ཐོག་མར་ཕྱི་ལོ་ ༡༩༩༤ ལོར་འགོ་བཙུགས་གནང་བ་དང། དེ་སྔ་ལས་འཆར་འདིའི་འོག་མཐོ་སློབ་ཀྱི་སློབ་མ་དྲུག་བདུན་ཙམ་ལས་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མེད་ཀྱང་། འདས་པའི་ལོ་དྲུག་གི་སྔོན་ཙམ་ནས་ལས་འཆར་དེར་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མང་དུ་ཕྱིན་ནས་ལོ་ལྟར་སློབ་མ་བུ་བཅོ་ལྔ་དང་བུ་མོ་བཅོ་ལྔ་བདམས་ནས་རྡ་སར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་བོད་པའི་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་། གོམས་གཤིས་སོགས་ཉམས་མྱོང་གསོག་རྒྱུ་ཙམ་མ་ཟད། བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ལས་ཁུངས་མ་ལག་དང་བཅས་པ་ཤེས་རྟོགས་བྱ་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག་ལོ་ ༢༠༡༤ ཟླ་ ༦ ཚེས་ ༡༣ ཉིན་གྱི་སྔ་དྲོའི་ཆུ་ཚོད་ ༩།༣༠ ནས་ ༡༢།༣༠ ཙམ་བར་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་དྲུང་ཆེ་བཀྲ་ཤིས་ཕུན་ཚོགས་ལགས་ཀྱིས་ཕྱི་དྲིལ་ལྷག་པ་ཚེ་རིང་དྲན་རྟེན་ཚོགས་ཁང་ནང་རྒྱ་གར་གྱི་རྒྱལ་ས་ལྡི་ལིར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་༸གོང་ས་༸སྐྱབས་མགོན་ཏཱ་ལའི་བླ་མ་མཆོག་གི་ཀུན་ཕན་བདེ་རྩས་གོ་སྒྲིག་འོག་རྒྱ་གར་རྒྱལ་ཡོངས་མཐོ་སློབ་ཁག་ ༢༩ ནང་སློབ་གཉེར་བྱེད་བཞིན་པའི་སློབ་ཕྲུག་གྲངས་ ༣༣ དང་ཐུག་འཕྲད་ཀྱིས་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་སྒྲོམ་གཞི་དང་སྲིད་བྱུས། དེ་བཞིན་ལྷན་ཁང་ཁག་གི་བྱེད་སྒོ་རྣམ་གསུམ་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་འབྲེལ་བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ངོས་ནས་དབུ་མའི་ལམ་གྱི་སྲིད་བྱུས་གཞིར་བཟུང་རྒྱ་ནག་གཞུང་དང་ལྷན་དུ་འབྲེལ་མོལ་བརྒྱུད་བོད་དོན་བདེན་མཐའ་གསལ་ཐབས་ལ་འབད་བརྩོན་ཞུ་བཞིན་ཡོད་སྐོར་སོགས་ཀྱི་གསུང་བཤད་ཟབ་རྒྱས་གནང་བ་མ་ཟད། དྲི་བར་ལན་འདེབས་ཀྱང་གནང་།སློབ་ཕྲུག་དེ་དག་ལ་ཟླ་བ་གཅིག་རིང་བཞུགས་སྒར་རྡ་སའི་ཁུལ་གྱི་བོད་པའི་དགོན་སྡེ་ཁག་ནང་བོད་ཀྱི་ཐུན་མིན་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་སོགས་ཀྱི་སྐོར་ངོ་སྤྲོད་དང་སྦྱོང་བརྡར་སྤྲོད་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག སྤྱིར་སྒུ་རུ་ཀུལ་ (Gurukul Programme) ལས་འཆར་འདི་བཞིན་ཐོག་མར་ཕྱི་ལོ་ ༡༩༩༤ ལོར་འགོ་བཙུགས་གནང་བ་དང། དེ་སྔ་ལས་འཆར་འདིའི་འོག་མཐོ་སློབ་ཀྱི་སློབ་མ་དྲུག་བདུན་ཙམ་ལས་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མེད་ཀྱང་། འདས་པའི་ལོ་དྲུག་གི་སྔོན་ཙམ་ནས་ལས་འཆར་དེར་མཉམ་ཞུགས་གནང་མཁན་མང་དུ་ཕྱིན་ནས་ལོ་ལྟར་སློབ་མ་བུ་བཅོ་ལྔ་དང་བུ་མོ་བཅོ་ལྔ་བདམས་ནས་རྡ་སར་རྟེན་གཞི་བྱས་པའི་བོད་པའི་ཆོས་དང་རིག་གཞུང་། གོམས་གཤིས་སོགས་ཉམས་མྱོང་གསོག་རྒྱུ་ཙམ་མ་ཟད། བོད་མིའི་སྒྲིག་འཛུགས་ཀྱི་ལས་ཁུངས་མ་ལག་དང་བཅས་པ་ཤེས་རྟོགས་བྱ་རྒྱུ་ཡིན་འདུག
\end{document}
```

Can someone please help me understand why the offset values are required to be set to -124 in order to align everything correctly? I am trying to attain some proper understanding of what I'm actually doing.

Thank you.

EDIT: [image: Output]
EDIT2: Let me try to rephrase my question: Why are the pages not aligned correctly with default offset values?

Using these settings:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1,3,5},nup=3x1,noautoscale=true,landscape,offset=0 0,turn=false]{a4pecha}
\includepdf[pages={6,4,2},nup=3x1,noautoscale=true,landscape,offset=0 0,turn=false]{a4pecha}
\end{document}
```

I get the following result:

[image: Witout offset]

EDIT3: Non-Tibetan version for those without Tibetan fonts installed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{paperwidth=29.7cm,paperheight=7cm,margin=0cm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newflowframe{21.7cm}{4.9cm}{4cm}{.9cm}

\newdynamicframe{29.7cm}{7cm}{0cm}{0cm}[standard]
\setdynamiccontents*{standard}{
    \vfil\hfil
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[color=black,very thick] (2.7,.93) rectangle +(24.3,5.14)
      (2.77,1) rectangle +(24.16,5)
      (3.77,1) rectangle +(.07,5)
      (25.97,1) rectangle +(.07,5);
    \node[rotate=-90] at (3.2,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
    \node[rotate=90] at (26.47,3.5) {\huge \thepage};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

EDIT4: I have used the exact same tex code as has been recommended, but the output is rotated for some reason:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1,3,5},nup=1x3]{a4pecha}
\includepdf[pages={6,4,2},nup=1x3]{a4pecha}
\end{document}
```

[image: non-tibetan result]

The plot thickens...

EDIT5: The problem is probably a bug in XeLaTeX.

Comment: Refer to page number 9, `pdfpages` manual. You will have a figure explaining `offset`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you for you reply. I have rephrased my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to use `nup=1x3` instead of `3x1` to have one column and three rows. `3x1` gives three columns and one row.

With `3x1` we get:

[image]

And with `1x3` we get:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1,3,5},nup=1x3,noautoscale=false,offset=0 0,]{pgfmanual}
\end{document}
```

Now the `offset`. With the following,

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1,nup=1x1,noautoscale=false,offset=0 0,]{pgfmanual}
\end{document}
```

you get

[image]

You will see that the bottom left end is having no gap. We use `offset` to insert some gap like `offset=1cm 1cm`

[image]

Hope things are clear now.

Now your file can be like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1,3,5},nup=1x3]{a4pecha}
\includepdf[pages={6,4,2},nup=1x3]{a4pecha}
\end{document}
```

giving

[image]

Are they aligned without using `offset`?

Bottom line: One has to choose correct options.

Comment: My heartiest congratulations on achieving 100K points!! You're a great asset to all users of this site.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how does these examples relate to my specific case that use entirely different formats? I kindly request that you try to use the format from the tex file I've used to create my PDF document and see if your statements are correct.

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much for the kind words. It was possible because I am standing on the shoulders of kind and nice people like you. Thank you for the support and encouragement. :)

Comment: @jollyroger May be I was not clear enough. But I could not compile your code as I don't have the tibetan font. My statements are correct. But how to use them for your example? This I can't show unless you provide the pdf file through some means. If you feel that this answer is not useful I can delete it :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar Just remove the tibetan content and replace it with lorem ipsum. The actual content isn't really important.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you. I have done exactly as you have instructed me, but the results are incorrectly rotated for some reason. I have added this information in EDIT4 in my original post. How come our output differs when we're both using the same tex files?

Comment: @jollyroger May be you are using outdated tex distribution? Try updating and see if it works.

Comment: @HarishKumar I have updated to the latest version of TexLive that is available for my distro, but still no cigar. I tried to use LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX and now it works. How did you render the PDF document? Perhaps there's a bug in XeLaTeX.